# NgRx custom state sanitizer

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Can anyone provide me with an example of a custom state sanitizer (StoreDevtoolsConfig.stateSanitizer) that takes effect **only** when the **redux tools** extension is active. Below is my custom sanitizer that takes effect always.

```
const stateSanitizer = (state: any) => {
   return {
    ...state,
    myView: {
        ...state.myView,
        myEditor: {
            ...state.myView.myEditor,
            myPhrases: 'LONG BLOB'
        }
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for is how to apply my custom sanitizer on the specific condition i.e. redux tools is active. So the below condition works for my issue

```
declare global {
 interface Window {
   __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose;
 }
}

const stateSanitizer = (state: any) => {
  if (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) {
     return {
         ...state,
         myView: {
           ...state.myView,
           myEditor: {
             ...state.myView.myEditor,
             myPhrases: 'LONG BLOB'
           }
         }
     };
  }
}
```